# #Java Mail Sender - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/FileTypeMap

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am creating Bean in Spring Configure Java class like :

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender configureJavaMailSender() {
JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        sender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        sender.setPort(587);
        sender.setUsername("sis.official@gmail.com");
        sender.setPassword("Goop@9790");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
        
        sender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);
        return sender;
    }
```

And i am getting the error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.FileTypeMap

Answer (score 1):

JavaMailSenderImpl has a dependency on Javax Activation

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```